# What is the regular expression pattern that implements my simple grammar?

Tags: regex, parsing

I need to process some legacy data and parse some vaguely formalized text fields. Instead of trying regex matches I was thinking in building some simple grammar definition and have some tool to parse the strings based on that.

Some example data of one of the columns to parse

```
08-JUL-13 To 09-AUG-13   BREAKFAST  0900 LUNCH  1230
```

or

```
08-JUL-13 To 22-AUG-13   LUNCH  1230
```

or

```
08 JUL 13 To 16 AUG 13  EAST WARD LUN  0200
```

So my grammar here would be something like this, what is the correct regex pattern?

```
DateRange:[DateWithOrWithoutDashes TO DateWithOrWithoutDashes]  {BlaBla}0..* {Break* Time}0..1 {Lun Time}0..1
```

Comment: Okay, I have removed the part that asks for the recommendation for any specific tools.

Comment: Should be easy enough to do with regex.

Comment: @leppie "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." - [source](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: @balexandre Regexes have their place - there are valid and invalid uses.  What is your reasoning in stipulating that their use for this particular problem would be invalid? (I agree with leppie that regexes seem to be suitable for this particular task, albeit not the only option.)

Comment: @balexandre: Hmmm, regex vs a lalr grammar... latter will probably cause more problems for (idiot) maintainers along the line... (and is overkill for this task)

Comment: actually a grammar seems more semantic for me, and because of the contextual manner of a parser, it would let for more flexible specifications for the lexical elements

Comment: @leppie take it as a friendly joke, it's quoted ... it's a good place to have it in it's context... regex is a problem for users that do not know how to use them, and when to use them.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai: A parser/lexer is overkill for this. Unless you have recursive elements, there is not really many reasons not to use regex here (and you pretty much wrote the regex in pseudo code already!)

Comment: Would love to post it as an answer, but question is on-hold.  Look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  It's a mature library and in past life my team used it to build SQL parser - so it definitely should be powerful enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
^(?<start_date>\d{2}-?[A-Z]{3}-?\d{2})\s+To\s+(?<end_date>\d{2}-?[A-Z]{3}-?\d{2})\s+(?:(?<type>[A-Z\s]+?)\s+(?<time>\d{4})\s*)+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ka_CpLrjN2CjVBIe)

C# code sample:

```
string[] lines = {
                     "08-JUL-13 To 09-AUG-13   BREAKFAST  0900 LUNCH  1230",
                     "08-JUL-13 To 22-AUG-13   LUNCH  1230",
                     "08 JUL 13 To 16 AUG 13  EAST WARD LUN  0200"
                 };
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"^(?<start_date>\d{2}[-\s][A-Z]{3}[-\s]\d{2})\s+To\s+(?<end_date>\d{2}[-\s][A-Z]{3}[-\s]\d{2})\s+(?:(?<type>[A-Z\s]+?)\s+(?<time>\d{4})\s*)+");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start date: {0}", m.Groups["start_date"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("End date: {0}", m.Groups["end_date"].Value);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.Groups["type"].Captures.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event type[{0}]: {1}", i, m.Groups["type"].Captures[i].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Event time[{0}]: {1}", i, m.Groups["time"].Captures[i].Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start date: 08-JUL-13
End date: 09-AUG-13
Event type[0]: BREAKFAST
Event time[0]: 0900
Event type[1]: LUNCH
Event time[1]: 1230

Start date: 08-JUL-13
End date: 22-AUG-13
Event type[0]: LUNCH
Event time[0]: 1230

Start date: 08 JUL 13
End date: 16 AUG 13
Event type[0]: EAST WARD LUN
Event time[0]: 0200
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will match all your examples.

```
([0-9])+(-| )([A-Z])+(-| )([0-9])+(-| )+(To)(-| )+([0-9])+(-| )([A-Z\])+(-| )([0-9])+(( )+([A-Z])+( )+([0-9])+)+
```

Comment: why all the capture groups?

Comment: and what to do with this regex? `.*` also will match all examples.

Comment: all he asked for was a regex pattern to match his grammar. "what is the correct regex pattern?"